# Motorcycle indicator flasher module

Tags: 555

I have built an electronic indicator flasher module based on 555 timers to replace a broken module for my motorcycle. I guess I could have just bought a replacement, but they are a little more expensive than just a flasher relay, and I thought it might be a little challenge to try and make it myself.
The switches for the left and right indicators are momentary switches, they connect to ground only when the button is pressed, the switch doesn't stay on. I've connected the switch to a relay to turn on the first 555. Each time the switch is pressed it turns the indicators on/off.
The lamps I believe are 10w each, and the mosfet was getting a little hot after 10 seconds.

So this is what I have so far, and it actually works, but it's only for one side...
[image]
Here are some questions and doubts maybe you can help me with...

1. Is there anything that I can do to make this more stable and/or protected, by the way I have a 0.1uF cap between pins 1(gnd) and 8(pwr) on both the 555's.
2. Would I have to build another for the other side, or can I somehow use the same one to switch to the other side?
3. How could the left switch cancel the right, or vice versa.
   e.g. if I am turning left (flashing left), then push the right switch, it should cancel the left flasher and flash the right.
4. My motorcycle doesn't have hazard lights, so I would like to add that feature, maybe by pushing both left and right switches together.

Thank you very much for reading,
Kind regards

Comment: I would use a PIC, or maybe an Arduino. The circuit would be very simple, and the programming would also be easy. A good beginner project.

Comment: The PIC is definitely something I'd like to look in to later, but for now I'd like to continue with the 555's since I've already spent a week playing with it, and have the components. Regards

Comment: buy a blinker module.   automotive is a rough environment for electronics. don't experiment with safety equipment.

Comment: Whilst I appreciate the advice about safety, I'd really like to see if I can do this, with help of course. The original blinker module is fully electronic, no relays. I have this half working, I could just make another for the other side and be done with it. I was hoping I might be able to learn something about electronics as well. Regards

Answer (score 0):

a basic automotive blinker-hazard circuit goes something like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhrxpx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

An important feature is that the blinker module comes before the switch, it first this seems like a problem for your design, but...

If you put the relay contacts after the MOSFET . and used diodes to send power from before the relays to your blinker circui you should get all the features you want by adding only one more relay and two diodes (edit: Three didodes, because one more is needed for the added relay)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f49pEl.png)</sup>

Comment: Mmm, interesting, I understand the concept, now just need to figure out the physical wiring of it all.
Many Thanks

Comment: Your diagram assumes the switches SW2 and SW3 are toggle switches, when I have push button switches. So I can't see a feasible way to do this.

Comment: I was assuming you'd have to hold the switch

Comment: No it's just a push switch, one momentary push for on, again for off.